# How to redirect text output to command line in Qt?

Tags: qt, command-line, io, console

If I have a `QApplication`, how can I redirect output (from qDebug) to the command line console that first started the executable?

Note that I don't want to create a new console.

Comment: Suggestion: If the application is non-GUI and just a CLI app then you should consider `QCoreApplication`.

Comment: The manual for [qDebug](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qDebug) mentions you can install your own [message handler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qInstallMessageHandler` to redirect `qDebug()` to your own function.

```
void qDebugRedirect(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        std::cout << msg.toStdString() << " from line: " << context.line;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

You want to install the message handler as early as possible:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qInstallMessageHandler(qDebugRedirect); // Install the handler
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Hello from qDebug";
    return a.exec();
}
```